# Formula for the chromatic symmetric function of a graph in terms of the graph's chromatic polynomial?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring, symmetric-functions

I know the chromatic symmetric function simplifies to the chromatic polynomial when 1's and 0's are subbed in for the x's. I was wondering if one could easily find the chromatic symmetric of a graph if given the chromatic polynomial of the graph?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The formulation “simplifies to the chromatic polynomial” is misleading – it sounds (to me) as if substituting values for some of the $x_i$ would yield the chromatic polynomial as a polynomial. In fact, you just get the *values* of the chromatic polynomial by substituting certain arguments into the chromatic symmetric function, but that’s not a “simplification” of a polynomial in the sense that some of the variables are substituted and what remains is still a polynomial. The variable $x$ in the chromatic polynomial doesn’t correspond to any of the variables in the chromatic symmetric function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could only be possible if graphs with the same chromatic polynomial always had the same chromatic symmetric function. It’s well-known that graphs with the same chromatic polynomial need not be isomorphic, and indeed one of the simplest examples of non-isomorphic graphs with identical chromatic polynomials already affords an example of graphs that have different chromatic symmetric functions despite having the same chromatic polynomial.

The [claw graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) on four vertices, $S_3$, has proper colourings in which three vertices have the same colour, whereas the [path graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) on four vertices, $P_4$, has no such colourings (since that would make at least two adjacent vertices the same colour). Thus, the symmetric chromatic function of $S_3$ contains variables to the third power, and that of $P_4$ does not. But these graphs are both trees and thus both have the chromatic polynomial $(x-1)^3x$.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Thank you for the detailed answer.